# mocking S3 download file operation for gzipped files

Tags: python, mocking, boto3, botocore

I am trying to mock some S3 operations and after banging my head against the stubber object, I tried doing something as follows:

```
def mock_make_api_call(self, operation_name, kwarg):
    if operation_name == "ListObjectsV2":
        return {
            "KeyCount": 1,
            "Contents": [
                {"Key": "sensor_1", "LastModified": "2021-11-30T12:58:14+00:00"}
            ],
        }
    elif operation_name == "GetObjectTagging":
        return {"TagSet": []}
    elif operation_name == "HeadObject":
        return {
            "ContentLength": 10,
            "ContentType": "gzip",
            "ResponseMetadata": {
                "Bucket": "1",
            },
        }
    elif operation_name == "GetObject":
        content = get_object_response()
        return {
            "ContentLength": len(content),
            "ContentType": "xml",
            "ContentEncoding": "gzip",
            "Body": content,
            "ResponseMetadata": {
                "Bucket": "1",
            },
        }
```

Ot is the s3 `download_file`operation which is giving me a headache. As far as I can tell it generates, the `HeadObject`and `GetObject`calls.

My content generation method is as follows:

```
def get_object_response():

    content = b"<some-valid-xml>"

    buf = BytesIO()
    compressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode="wb")
    compressed.write(content)
    compressed.close()

    return buf.getvalue()
```

The way it gets used is:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    s3_client.download_file(Bucket=..., Key=..., Filename=tmp.name)
```

However, my test fails with:

```
elf = <s3transfer.utils.StreamReaderProgress object at 0x116a77820>
args = (262144,), kwargs = {}

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
>       value = self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
E       AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I simply cannot figure out how to encode the response so that the generated content can be saved.

Comment: It looks like the value of 'Body' should be an IO-object, not the raw bytes. Try `buf.seek(0); return buf` in the get_object_response-method

Comment: I tried that as well but no cigar